# Create a test branch with the same name as the release branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I would like to know if there's a way to fix this or whether this is going to cause an issue.

We usually create a test branch and merged everything to it to get it tested

Then we merge all that into a release branch

I called my branch as the release branch and set the upstream to it and merged everything into it and pushed it.

After finding out, I thought this shouldn't have happened as the branch already existed but it did allow me.

Is there a way to fix this as I should have my changes into the release branch

Thank you

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue and post the commands and their results here?

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe : you updated the release branch to the state of your test branch.

To confirm that : you can run

```
git fetch
git log --oneline --graph that-branch origin/that-branch
```

The second command should display something like :

```
* <sha1> (HEAD -> that-branch, origin/that-branch) my last commit
* <sha2> my commit 2
* <sha3> my commit 3
* <sha4> the release branch should be at this commit
* <sha5> commit
...
```

If such is the case : the way to fix this is instruct the remote repo to go back to the correct commit (`<sha4>` in the diagram above)

```
git push --force-with-lease origin <sha4>:that-branch
```

*note :* this is a force push, you will have to tell all of your coworkers to run `git fetch` to update their local repo, and to take relevant actions if they need to rebase their work.

---

One usual way to avoid accidentally pushing on the release branch is :   when you use a git server such as `github` or `bitbucket` or `gitlab` or ..., you can specify that some branches are *protected*, and should only be updated through merge requests.

If this suits your workflow, you can turn this option on the central repository.